# How to add FrameLayout inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi i am new for android in my app i am adding Frame-layout inside LinearLayout but Frame-Layout and it's inside fields are not adding

my code is below please help me some one

### main.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent'"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight ="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:text="something" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frame" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what you exactly want to do? attach same reference image!